# Is there a specific term for words which are embedded in others, e.g. leave in cleave, or hell in shell?

Tags: terminology

I am not referring to contronyms (cleave) but rather the playful use, frequently in poetry, of words chosen specifically for their embedded-word qualities.

Comment: In computer land, it is called a [**substring**](https://www.lexico.com/definition/substring).

Comment: If the embedded words are synonymous, they are called a    **kangaroo word** and a **joey word**. E.g. *alone= lone, one*. (en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kangaroo_word)

Comment: This isn't about English; this is about spelling. _Hell_ is not embedded in _shell_; there's no /h/.